# an arithmetic calculation on each number in a txt file by perl

Tags: perl

I am very new to programming. I need to read a file line-by-line in perl. The text file has two columns and 100,000 rows all having numbers. I need to apply this formula (/16)*100 on each number and the result should be a separate file again with 2 columns and 100000 rows.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'results_AH.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

while (my $row = <$fh>) {
  chomp $row;
  print "$row\n";
}
print "done\n";
```

This is what I have. The file looks like (just a part). The calculation is to be done on both columns and each number.Please help :)

```
AH LHH
5   0
4   0
3   0
5   0
5   0
4   0
3   0
4   0
4   0
4   0
5   0
5   0
3   0
4   0
```

Comment: Where do you stuck?

Answer (score 6):

Hard-coding a filename is almost always a bad idea. If you read from `<>` then you can pass any filename on the command line. Also, it's more Perlish to read data into `$_`.

```
while (<>) {
  # do stuff with $_
}
```

So what do we want to do? Well first let's split the data into individual columns and store them in an array.

```
my @numbers = split;
```

Notice that `split()` works on `$_` and splits on whitespace by default.

Now we need to do your calculation. We can do it on all elements of `@numbers` using `map()`.

```
my @new_numbers = map { $_ * 100 / 16 } @numbers;
```

And finally we want to print our results. That's as simple as:

```
print "@new_numbers\n";
```